# Different flow in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, appdelegate

I have a question about iOS Storyboard.
In my storyboard I have my flow:

1. Navigation Controller;
2. Login View Controller;
3. Detail View Controller;

This is the regular flow if there isn't a valid user session.
When I start the app I need to check if there is a valid user session. In this case I need to visualize directly the 3° (Detail View Controller)
I'm not sure but I think that I need to make the check about user session in my Appdetegate. How can I load, in this case, directly the 3° View Controller?

Comment: You want to switch directly to DetailViewController in AppDelegate?

Comment: yes, are there better ideas?

Comment: You could make the detail controller the root of the navigation controller and have a modal segue from the detail controller to the login controller. Then once the app starts, in the detail controller, in ViewDidAppear you could do your check and immediate segue to the Login view modally. This also lets you easily return to the detail view once the user logs in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1**

I think what you can do is not check a valid session at all. Here is what I think

1) Create a `BOOL` called isUserSignedIn that is initially set to `NO` and save that in you NSUserDefaults. (AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method)

2) Once user makes a valid Login set the `BOOL` to `YES`. Save `BOOL` in `NSUserdefaults`

3) When user logs out set `BOOL` to `NO`

4) Everytime the user opens the app. In `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` check of the BOOL is yes or no. if no loads LoginViewController. if yes do nothing.

This is how I'd do it. Always save every BOOL changes in NSUserdefaults and loads from there.

**SOLUTION 2**
But if you want to load your DetailViewController in your AppDelegate use this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

    //check your login session here…

    //if session ok loads DetailViewController
    DetailViewController* detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:detail
                                                 animated:NO
                                               completion:nil];
    //if not 
    // do something..


    return YES;
}
```